AWS CloudFormation: Programmatic conditions in ForEach
I am trying to conditionally create multiple resources. The CFT I intend to specify would like something like the following:
{
 "Transform": "AWS::LanguageExtensions",
 ... 
 "Resources" : {
        "Fn::ForEach::Zones": [
            "Zone",
            ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
            {
                "Queue${Zone}": {
                    "Type" : "AWS::SQS::Queue"
                    "Condition" :  { "Fn::Sub": "CreateQueueInZone${Zone}" },
                },
            }
        ]
  }
}

The issue is that Condition specifications cannot use functions (ref).
What is a possible workaround to the above limitation?
The above template gives a
Fragment returned by transform AWS::LanguageExtensions is null.

error.

There is no workaround, unless you create your own custom resource to deal with that, or rewrite your template to climate the need for such conditions.
